# Help with workflow

Tags: workflow

I have a requirement in which I need to Update Account and Contact Owner to some ABC user simultaneously when account Owner or the contact owner is some XYZ user along with some contacts that are associated with some pardot score. Here pardot score comes from a installed package pardot and all the fields related to workflow are present on contact. how can I achieve it. Any help? It is quite urgent requirement.

I dont have problem with Rule criteria but the Action.I have formula correctly written but i am in trouble while updating fields. I can very easily update Contact owner by writting workflow on contact but the issue arises with Account Owner.

You mitght say, I can write another workflow on acccount and update it but issue is i need to evaluate fields which are present on account i.e. Pardot Score as mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Process Builder for something like this. If you understand WF then you're qualified to use the PB. You can do more with it.

If you need more info how to do it, add as much details as you can and we can try together.

Comment: Is there any way to update Contact field on Account

Answer (score 0):

I would have made this a comment to the first answer but it tells me that it is to long so I am forced to add a new answer.

Yes. 
1) Go to  Setup 
2) Search for Process builder 
 
3) Click New 
4) Choose Account Object 
5) Select "when a record is created or edited" and click save 
6) For Criteria Name give it any name and choose "No criteria—just execute the actions!" and cick save 
7) Create a new IMMEDIATE ACTIONS 
8) Give it any name you want, click account/contacts such that it shows "[Account].Contacts" in the Record* text box 
9) In the Filter the records you update based on these conditions section choose a criteria like you would in a Workflow. 
10) Give a new value to update the field in the contact in the next section below. 
11) Save. 
12) Click on Activate or it won't fire off.
 
If I was clear enough and you followed this, when an account record is saved, it fires off the Process and it should update a contact for a given account based on your criteria.
 
If this answer helped you why not vote for it.

Comment: Hello Happy SF Guy,

I do have idea about process builder but my question is how to rollup from parent to child i.e I need to fetch contact field to account by rollup summary or in short I want to access Child from parent wherein we can do vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

I opted for trigger for the above question. I am posting the trigger for above scenario:

trigger ContactRollUp on Contact (after delete, after insert, after undelete,after update) 
{

```
List<Contact> conList = new  List<Contact>() ;
if (Trigger.isDelete)
    conList = Trigger.old;
else
    conList = Trigger.new;

// Get list of Accounts
Set<ID> accId = new Set<ID>();
for (Contact con : conList )
{
        accId.add(con.AccountId);
}

Map<ID, Contact> conMap = new Map<ID, Contact>([select Id, pi__score__c, AccountId from Contact where AccountId in :accId AND pi__score__c >0 ]);

Map<ID, Account> accMap = new Map<ID, Account>([select Id, Pardot_Score_Contact__c from Account where Id in :accId]);

for (Account acc : accMap.values()) 
{
    Set<ID> conId = new Set<ID>();
    for (Contact con : conMap.values()) 
    {
        if (con.AccountId == acc.Id)
            conId.add(con.Id);
    }
    if (acc.Pardot_Score_Contact__c != conId.size())
        acc.Pardot_Score_Contact__c  = conId.size();
}

update accMap.values();
```

}